# i am trying to Get the least price of available rooms in next April

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT  rooms.room_id,rooms.room_number,rooms.room_floor,rooms.hotel_id,rooms.category_id,rooms.room_price , rooms.room_area, MIN(rooms.room_price) AS LEAST price
FROM bookings,rooms
WHERE bookings.room_id = rooms.room_id
AND bookings.room_id IN (SELECT bookings.room_id FROM bookings WHERE bookings.check_in  BETWEEN '2019-04-00 00:00:00' AND '2019-05-00 00:00:00') 
GROUP BY rooms.room_id,rooms.room_number,rooms.room_floor,rooms.hotel_id,rooms.category_id,rooms.room_price , rooms.room_area
ORDER by
```

1.sorry this code
2.this the second code that i tried

```
SELECT    rooms.room_id,rooms.room_number,rooms.room_floor,rooms.hotel_id,rooms.category_id,rooms.room_price , rooms.room_area, MIN(rooms.room_price)
FROM bookings,rooms
WHERE bookings.room_id = rooms.room_id
AND  bookings.check_in BETWEEN '2019-04-00 00:00:00' AND '2019-05-00 00:00:00'
AND  bookings.check_out  BETWEEN '2019-04-00 00:00:00' AND '2019-05-00 00:00:00'
AND  bookings.real_check_in  BETWEEN '2019-04-00 00:00:00' AND '2019-05-00 00:00:00'
AND  bookings.real_check_out  BETWEEN '2019-04-00 00:00:00' AND '2019-05-00 00:00:00'
GROUP BY rooms.room_id,rooms.room_number,rooms.room_floor,rooms.hotel_id,rooms.category_id,rooms.room_price , rooms.room_area
```

how to get the right answer?
this confusing its give me sometime all value or no answer

```
CREATE TABLE `rooms` (
`room_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`room_number` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`room_floor` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`hotel_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`category_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`room_price` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`room_area` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`room_id`),
INDEX `FK_rooms_hotels` (`hotel_id`),
INDEX `FK_rooms_categories` (`category_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_rooms_categories` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`category_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_rooms_hotels` FOREIGN KEY (`hotel_id`) REFERENCES `hotels` (`hotel_id`)
)
COLLATE='ucs2_general_ci'
 ENGINE=InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT=39
```

i need the right answer

and why do we need type it like this

```
      CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
`booking_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`room_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`customer_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`check_in` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`check_out` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`real_check_in` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`real_check_out` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`booking_id`),
INDEX `FK_bookings_rooms` (`room_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_bookings_rooms` FOREIGN KEY (`room_id`) REFERENCES `rooms` (`room_id`)
)
 COLLATE='ucs2_general_ci'
 ENGINE=InnoDB
 AUTO_INCREMENT=68
 ;
```

;

Comment: Asking a question with just a non-working query is like asking for directions in the manner of "I want to get to my hotel. I took a right turn, then two left turns. I didn't arrive there."

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: can you help me

Answer (score 0):

This is my third attempt, and I still get query warnings.

```
SELECT  
    rooms.room_id, rooms.room_number, rooms.room_floor,
    rooms.hotel_id, rooms.category_id, rooms.room_price, 
    rooms.room_area, MIN(rooms.room_price) 
FROM
    bookings,rooms
WHERE 
    bookings.room_id = rooms.room_id
    AND bookings.check_in >= '2019-04-00 00:00:00' <= '2019-05-00 00:00:00'
    AND bookings.check_out  >= '2019-04-00 00:00:00' <= '2019-05-00 00:00:00'
    AND bookings.real_check_in  >= '2019-04-00 00:00:00' <= '2019-05-00 00:00:00'
    AND bookings.real_check_out >= '2019-04-00 00:00:00' <= '2019-05-00 00:00:00'
GROUP BY 
    rooms.room_id, rooms.room_number, rooms.room_floor, 
    rooms.hotel_id, rooms.category_id, rooms.room_price, rooms.room_area
```

Answer (score 0):

this my forth try

```
 SELECT  r.room_id
     , r.room_number
     , r.room_floor
     , r.hotel_id
     , r.category_id
     , r.room_price 
     , r.room_area
     , MIN(r.room_price) 
FROM bookings b
     , rooms r
 WHERE b.room_id = r.room_id
  AND b.room_id not IN (SELECT bookings.room_id FROM bookings  WHERE '2019-04-00 00:00:00'  <= bookings.check_in and '2019-05-00 00:00:00' >=   bookings.check_out) 
GROUP BY r.room_id
     , r.room_number
     , r.room_floor
     , r.hotel_id
     , r.category_id
     , r.room_price 
     , r.room_area
ORDER BY MIN(r.room_price)
```